# Should I use "grown" or "grown to" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> The pile of garbage had grown (to) half his height.

To me, "had grown half his height" sounds natural. However, a native speaker told me I should add *to.*

Should I add a *to*? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it needs "to". Something can grow *to* a measure, or it can grow *by* a measure.

"Grown *to* half his height" means that, as it stands now, it is half his height.

If it said "grown *by* half his height" that would mean that its existing height had *increased* by whatever half his height was.

Without a preposition, "grown" would mean that the subject had grown something else, for example, "he had grown some sunflowers".

Comment: Excellent answer that covers all the necessary points.